# Python 2.7 dist utils with several c extensions: how to move source object files

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python method that imports several source object files from various extensions.  My setup.py file has worked fine for years.  Each extension is kept in a separate directory under a folder called extensions.  At the bottom of the script I merely move the various source object files from within the extensions/ directory tree to the upmost directory using shell commands within the python setup.py script.

I understand that --inplace is an option but most of our users will only know to type python setup.py install.  I spent several hours working through python docs and stackoverflow and have not found a solution that will take care of this.

The file structure is simple

> my_script.py
>
> setup.py
>
> extensions/
>
> extension_1/
> extension_1.cpp
> build/
>
> extension_2/
> extension_2.cpp
> build/

where the *.so object files need to be in the top-most directory to be installed and used correctly.  Note that the folders extension_* are inside the folder extensions/.

I want to know if there is a solution I can put into my setup.py script to avoid the shell commands that copy the *.so files from their separate build/lib* directories to the upmost directory so that when installed the extension modules are available to the python module(s) that import them.